# Branch and Bound vs Evolutionary Algorithms

Tags: optimization

On an informal level, I have heard the following statements being made:

- The "Branch and Bound" Algorithm has the ability to provide exact solutions to optimization algorithms, but can take a long time to run.
- Evolutionary Algorithms can only provide approximate answers, but take less time to run.

**My Question:** Are there any references which quantify this above statement using mathematical formulas? Would any of these references be able to provide detailed comparisons regarding the theoretical behavior of both types of algorithms (e.g. strength of convergence, varying levels of convexity, etc.)?

Thanks!